# How to install PHP intl extension in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, zend-framework2

I have a hard time to find exact method to install PHP intl extension in **Ubuntu 14.04**.

I tried with `sudo apt-get install php5-intl` but displays error `Unable to locate package`.

I really need this extension for Zend Framework 2 , because of above missing extension I am getting error like this

**ERROR:** `Zend\I18n\Validator component requires the intl PHP extension`

I am using PHP 5.5.9.

How can I install `PHP-intl` extension in a correct way ?

Comment: just `sudo apt-get install php-intl`

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI,still same error

Answer (score 174):

For **php5** on Ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

For **php7** on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

For **php7.2** on Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl
```

**Anyway restart your apache after**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

> IMPORTANT NOTE: Keep in mind that your php in your terminal/command
>   line has **NOTHING** todo with the php used by the apache webserver!

If the extension is already installed you should try to enable it. Either in the php.ini file or from command line.

Syntax:

php:

```
phpenmod [mod name]
```

apache:

```
a2enmod [mod name]
```

Comment: Note that as of PHP7, the version number si no more required: `apt-get install php-intl` will work.

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-intl does it automatically for your version

Comment: Depends on the version you want. The main repositories are already updated so you have to specify the version if you dont work with th elatest. Also its more fail-safe to specify the version so you always get the same deendencies except you upgrade. Autoupgrades CAN break your system and are pretty hard to find

Comment: First run `sudo apt-get update`. Then, `sudo apt-get install php-intl`. It will automatically update php.ini. Then run `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: "IMPORTANT NOTE: Keep in mind that your php in your terminal/command line has NOTHING todo with the php used by the apache webserver!" - This had me runnning in circles a few years ago, it maddening!

Comment: for the  php8   sudo apt install php8.1-intl

Comment: @Tokeeen.com   for the multiple php installations version needs to be specified for the enable ones

Answer (score 23):

install it from terminal

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

Answer (score 10):

May be universe repository is disabled, here is [your package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/php/php5-intl) in it

Enable it

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And install

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

Comment: I am getting this `error` now `php5-intl : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4) but 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.20 is to be installed`

Comment: look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/661745/why-do-i-get-an-error-trying-to-install-php5-intl

Answer (score 8):

So, I have problem with it. If you can't install see below.
And previously you have to add repository.

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

2.1) `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2`

or

2.2) `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/nginx`

After that you can install

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl
```

Where 7.4 your php version.

Comment: sadly this somehow doesn't work in ubuntu 18.04 lts

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu 20.04, PHP 7.4 use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl
```

replace 7.4 with your PHP version

Answer (score 4):

For php 5.6 on ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-intl
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

then restart your server

Answer (score 2):

This method works for me to install PHP intl extension in **Ubuntu 18.04** and **nginx**

```
sudo apt install php7.2-intl -y
```

Answer (score 0):

you could search with 
`aptitude search intl`
after you can choose the right one, for example
`sudo aptitude install php-intl`
and finally
`sudo service apache2 restart`

good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers without enabling it in .ini file it did not work for me.

You can enable this extension in **php.ini** file by adding this line:

```
extension=intl.so
```