# Laravel: error when trying to change locale faker to he_IL

Tags: php, laravel, faker, laravel-seeding

When i'm changing my faker locale to he_IL,
I get this error:

```
userName failed with the selected locale. Try a different locale or activate the "intl" PHP extension.
```

How can i fix it, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using WAMP, XAMPP, go to your `php.ini` file and remove the `;` to activate the extension:

`;extension=php_intl.dll`

For ubuntu check this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243461/how-to-install-php-intl-extension-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Thanks just posted my answer at the same time with yours :)

Comment: I can't find this line in `php.ini` on XAMPP. Does anyone know why?