# search domain name availability laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know how to build on of those Domain Name Availability search that many hosting companies have and use it with laravel 5.4 project.

I tried this package (io-developer/php-whois) but unfortunately i got this error

```
- io-developer/php-whois 3.0.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
```

Also i tried other package (helgesverre/domain-availability) but again i got a same error and i don't know how to fix this error and i'm asking for another solution.

Can you someone please help me in this

Comment: Your server is lacking the ext-intl PHP extension. If your server is Ubuntu based then this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243461/how-to-install-php-intl-extension-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work with me because i'm using windows 10